# Reliable method to determine if IPv6 is supported in compiled version of PHP?

Tags: php, ipv6

What is a reliable method to determine if the compiled version of PHP being used supports IPv6?

I would have thought this to be more straight forward.

- I first came across [this post](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php#104917).
- However after testing PHP 7.1 the results are opposite of what I expected.
- I then came across this [PHP bug post](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70252).
- I then ran this code which *returned absolutely no output*.

---

```
 if (extension_loaded('sockets')) {echo 'sockets and maybe IPv6?';}
 else {echo 'No sockets, so...no IPv6?';}
```

Whether sockets is enabled or disabled doesn't seem to prevent this PHP build from working with IPv6 so I'm back at the starting point.

So what is a *reliable* method for ensuring that IPv6 is supported in PHP? An acceptable answer must *not* trigger any level or errors or warnings.

Comment: "I then ran this code which returned absolutely no output." You forgot the `echo`.

Comment: As I know, IPv6 support depends on the OS rather than PHP. And the example code that checks for extension has nothing to do with IPv4 or IPv6. It just checks if you can use plain sockets in php. Checking for `defined('AF_INET6')` is the right way to see it IPv6 was force disabled.

Comment: @astax So if `defined('AF_INET6')` is defined then IPv6 was forcibly *disabled*? I just want to ensure if it is possible that PHP won't support IPv6 for some reason that I can have my software let me know so I can redo the PHP install if need-be. An official reference would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just move this out of comment section

You can check if `AF_INET6` is defined only if sockets extension is loaded. So the code logic would be like this

```
if (extension_loaded('sockets')) {
   if (defined('AF_INET6'))
      echo "IPv6 is supported";
   else
      echo "IPv6 is disabled";
} else {
   echo "Can't determine if IPv6 is supported";
}
```

Comment: Also, although somewhat stupid idea, you can grab the output of `phpinfo()` using output buffering and see if it contains string `--disable-ipv6`